# how to check netconnection in firewall & proxy environment in c#

Tags: c#, proxy, firewall, internet-connection

i have used the following code to check for internet connection it works perfectly without firewall & proxy. how do i check net connection in firewall & proxy mode. please help me

```
private static ManualResetEvent connectDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
public static bool IsInternetConnected()
{
    int Desc;
    string[] sitesList = { "www.google.co.in", "www.microsoft.com", "www.sun.com" };
    bool status;
    status = InternetGetConnectedState(out Desc, 0);
    if (status)
    {
        try
        {
        connectDone.Reset();
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

        client.BeginConnect(sitesList[0], 80, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
        connectDone.WaitOne(1000, false);
        if (client.Connected)
        status = true;
        else
        status = false;
        client.Close();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
        BringDebug.WriteToLog("BringNet", "IsInternetConnected", ex.Message);
        return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

    return status;
}

private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        TcpClient client1 = (TcpClient)ar.AsyncState;
        client1.EndConnect(ar); // Complete the connection.
        connectDone.Set(); // trigger the connectDone event 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you use `WebRequest` instead of `TcpClient`, it should use the system default proxy etc. It'll also be less code :)

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
        request.Timeout = 1000;

        try
        {
            using (var response = request.GetResponse()) {}
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No connection");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but i think it is slower method than previous one , is there any idea to speed up

Comment: When you say you *think* it is slower - have you measured it? Admittedly it will actually fetch a response rather than just connecting, but I'd expect it to be *adequately* fast.

Comment: (One option for speeding it up by the way, at the cost of some complexity: make the three requests in parallel.)

Comment: i get "The operation has timed out" message every first time i ran the code

Comment: i get the same error again eventhough, i set the timeout to 2500

Comment: That suggests it really is timing out. Try using Wireshark to see what's going on.

Comment: You could speed up the request by setting the method to HEAD then you will only get headers returned